# Invalid action error on tic tac toe minimax function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a minimax algorithm for tic tac toe in cs50ai, but I just can't seem to get my head around it. I can't seem to understand how to get a value back from my recursion between maxval and minval. 
How can my script find a value for the game state and compare it to the infinite value and how can I relate that value to the initial move that the for loop is checking out? Currently my code always raises the exception of an invalid action. This makes me feel like it is running until the board is empty and then trying to perform another action.
I have done so much reading and looking through different codes but I can't figure out how to make this work. Any help and hints are appreciated.

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""

import math
import copy

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None
    if board == initial_state():
        return X
    if checkturn(board) == X:
        return X
    elif checkturn(board) == O:
        return O

    #return turn
    #raise NotImplementedError


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    action_set = set()
    coord_x = 0
    coord_y = 0
    board_size = 3
    for row in board:
        for item in row:
            if item is None:
                action_set.add((coord_x, coord_y))

            coord_y += 1
            if coord_y == board_size:
                coord_y = 0
        coord_x += 1

    return action_set

    #raise NotImplementedError


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    # If the action is not in the action set raise an exception that the move is invalid
    #
    # DISCUSS THIS WITH HAMISH
    action_set = actions(board)
    # Make a copy of the previous boards to reference
    parentboard = copy.deepcopy(board)

    if parentboard[action[0]][action[1]] is not None:
        raise Exception("Invalid action")
    #Make a new updated board to return so we don't overwrite the old ones
    if action in action_set:
        newboard = board
        newboard[action[0]][action[1]] = player(board)
        return newboard


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """
    row = [[board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]],
           [board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]],
           [board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]]]

    col = [[board[0][0], board[1][0], board[2][0]],
           [board[0][1], board[1][1], board[2][1]],
           [board[0][2], board[1][2], board[2][2]]]
    diag = [[board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]],
            [board[2][0], board[1][1], board[0][2]]]
    for item in row:
        win = check_xo(item)
        if win is not None:
            return win
    for item in col:
        check_xo(item)
        if win is not None:
            return win
    for item in diag:
        check_xo(item)
        if win is not None:
            return win



    #raise NotImplementedError


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    action_set = actions(board)
    # Check if the actionset is empty. IF so game is over(True)
    if len(action_set) == 0:
        return True
    # Check if someone has won the game. If so game is over (True).
    if winner(board) == X or winner(board) == O:
        return True
    else:
        return False

    #raise NotImplementedError


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return -1
    elif winner(board) is None:
        return 0
    #raise NotImplementedError


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    #if terminal(board):
    #    return None
    if player(board) == X:
        v = -math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            v = minval(result(board, action))
            if v > value:
                return action

    if player(board) == O:
        v = math.inf
        for action in actions(board):
            v = maxval(result(board, action))
            if v < value:
                return action



# My added functions start #
def maxval(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    value = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        max(value, minval(result(board, action)))
    return value


# Find the move that produces the highest Value

def minval(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    value = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        min(value, maxval(result(board, action)))
    return value


def checkturn(board):
    xCount = 0
    oCount = 0
    # Count how many Os and Xs are on the board
    for i in board:
        for j in i:
            if j == X:
                xCount += 1
            if j == O:
                oCount += 1
    #If O is less than x, then it's O's turn, otherwise it's Xs turn
    if oCount < xCount:
        return O
    else:
        return X


def check_xo(item):
    if item == ['X', 'X', 'X']:
        return X
    if item == ['O', 'O', 'O']:
        return O
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: In `maxval` and `minval` you never assign the result of `max()` to anything.  Also, those functions are currently identical; shouldn't the logic be inverted in one of them?

Comment: You're right, they should be inverted, I must have reverted it back while trying to fix it. I have changed that but the error remains.
I can't figure out how to use the result of max after assigning it.

Comment: Presumably you want to use `value = max(...)`.

Comment: This is also a great chance to break out your [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  You should be able to step through this code one line at a time, inspect values of variables, and figure out why things aren't behaving as expected.

Comment: I would venture that something is wrong with your minval and maxval functions. The board state is somehow changed......just a step toward debugging your program. I could fix it all but I bet you would prefer solving it yourself.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've tried stepping through it all with the debugger and for some reason all I can find is that when it gets to having 2 squares remaining it reliably somehow picks an action that should is not empty on the board. Obviously the action is being picked before the action set is being created but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to remedy this. Any chance of being a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I am tryna do same thing but whenever I run my code I choose my player and put one move then next turn getting error